# How to add europe-west2 as region argument in kubeflow ml-engine/deploy.py and components

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I am working on building and deploying a ML model using Kubeflow Pipelines (KFP) on GCP in a region other than `us-central1`.

I am able to use KFP's `train` container in the pipeline as [_train.py](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/gcp/container/component_sdk/python/kfp_component/google/ml_engine/_train.py) has a `region` argument where I can pass my region.

However, while executing the deployment stage in the KFP pipeline, I am getting an error as it cannot be executed because of no region arguments in [_deploy.py](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/gcp/container/component_sdk/python/kfp_component/google/ml_engine/_deploy.py).

My question is: how can I add the region as an argument in [_deploy.py](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/gcp/container/component_sdk/python/kfp_component/google/ml_engine/_deploy.py) and the other components that would require it?

Can someone please explain the way to do it with source code or an example for reference?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [kpt](https://googlecontainertools.github.io/kpt/) tool already supports the `location` and `gcloud.compute.region` [parameters](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/#configure-kubeflow) for the deployment's region. However, Kubeflow Pipelines doesn't yet fully support regional deployments but it's being worked on - see this open [gcp-blueprints](https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints/issues/6) issue.